# Collaboration in a project with dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, devops, alm

I'm a DevOps engineer creating CI processes for projects. I was wondering what is the best way to deal with the following scenario: Let's say I have a C++ project (using CLion + CMake) with several developers working on it. Now in order to be built, the project has some libraries it depends on. That automatically reflects on the CMakeLists.txt file that should know where to look for those libraries.

Basically the problem is that we need to take care that every developer has these libraries in the correct paths on his machine, which is a big hassle.

One approach to handle this would be to keep those dependencies in the repository. That's great since all the developer has to do is to clone the repo and he got everything he needs in order to run compilation. But as we know, keeping binaries in SCM is not a good practice.

The question is, is there a good method to handle project dependencies in a C++ project?

I know that with C# for example, we could use NuGet packages to handle these kind of scenarios. So we'd have a NuGet repository in Artifactory that would host the dependency packages, and then in our project we'd keep a reference to the required packages, and in build time we would just download the dependecies and build the project.
Is there something alike in C++ (Running on Linux I mean)?

Hope the question is clear enough lol, had a hard time wording it..

Comment: Using CMake should have eliminated the need for having the same paths as long as you don't put full paths in the CMakeLists.txt and use find_package(). Each user could set environment variables to help CMake find the packages they need to find.

Comment: Well, if you are creating your build system on cmake foundation then you can implement dependency management as well. DIY that is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how those dependencies are delivered and packaged. If whoever maintains your dependencies took CMake into account you can probably use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). If they didn't account for this, but they support [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) you can use [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html). Now all you need to do is let the developers know what dependencies they need to install. This should work regardless of the OS used for development.

Other solutions may involve pulling and building the dependency code when you build your project (for example, by using git submodules if possible, or [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FetchContent.html#id1), but this can become a nightmare if you have a lot of dependencies).

Additionally, you can try using a package manager like [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg), or [conan](https://conan.io/) (if all your dependencies are available there), or [CPM](https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake).

Comment: There is also [https://conan.io/](https://conan.io/)

Comment: @drescherjm oops, I completely forgot about conan. I edited my answer.